# Grouping Regular expression BackReferences

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have the following RegEx

```
id=(.*?) | id="(.*?)"
```

The reason for this is I am trying to replace Ids from the browsers DOM using JavaScript. IE, however strips quotes from element atributes as it appears not to require them in the DOM

The problem I have is that the backrefererences from each alternate statement are in separate groups ($1 and $2)  as the match is only one OR the other can I return both the backreference as a single backreference?

EDIT:

```
<div id="test1" /><div id=test2 />
```

will match as follows

```
    match         |  $1   |   $2
--------------------------------
    id="test1"    | test1 |
    id=test2      |       |  test2
```

I just want both backreferences to be added to $1

Comment: Can you post an example showing the problem?

Comment: Have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id="?([\w-]*)"?
```

Comment: Nope, it also needs to match colons, periods and the first character of an ID has to be a letter.

Comment: *sigh* can we just assume the OP is going to manage that himself given the question was about grouping, not about valid ID strings?

Answer (score 0):

what about:

```
id="?(.*?)"?
```

*(possibly that . should be [^"] - I didn't test it)*

Comment: This will only match id="  and misses the rest

Comment: should have been "?([^"]*)"? then, c'est la vie

Comment: No, the problem is that everything after the equals sign is optional.

Comment: But yes, you should have used [^"]* as well.

Comment: um, no /id="?([^"]*)"?/ works exactly as expected - the ? being equivalent to {0,1} when used as a quantifier

Comment: It works becasue the dot was replaced with the negated character class, AND because the reluctant quantifier was replaced with a greedy one.  Both changes are necessary.

Comment: so as per my comment an hour before yours? I did say it wasn't tested

Answer (score 0):

I’d use

```
id\s*=\s*("[^"]*"|'[^']*'|[^\s>]*)
```

This would match

```
id="foo"
id='bar'
id=baz
```

But to retrieve just the attribute value, you have to strip the `"` or `'` at the begin/end if it’s surrounded by quotes.